# Compare a row with another rows with similar and partially similar value in same dataframe and set value to new column

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a csv dataset like this

[Dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f57mG.png)

I need to assign a new value GP to SP, indicating follow-up from the general clinic to the specialist. The way is by comparing each row with another similar row based on ID Number and Visit Date.

The condition for a true gp_to_sp is something like this

1. Diagnosis(b) equal to or partially equal to Diagnosis (a)
2. Panel(b) is SP and Panel(a) is GP

**CODE 1**

```
df['Visit Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Visit Date'])

def gp_to_sp(g):
    return (
        (g['Diagnosis'] == g['Diagnosis'].shift()) &
        (g['Panel'] == 'Panel SP') &
        (g['Panel'].shift() == 'Panel GP')
    )
newdf = df.assign(gp_to_sp=df.groupby('ID Number').apply(gp_to_sp).droplevel(0))
```

**Output**

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/swklr.png)

Currently, my code above is working but as you can see, the visit ID (7) for ID Number (1002) is falsely flagged as False because the Diagnosis between Visit ID (2) and Visit ID (7) is not exactly same (only partially same). The correct value should be True as the patient visit SP from GP but only to treat his Back Pain.

**CODE 2**

I tried to use str.contains() function like example below but got ‘unhashable type: Series ‘error. Probably because g['Diagnosis'].shift() is series obj not string.

```
def gp_to_sp(g):
    return (
        (g['Diagnosis'].str.contains(g['Diagnosis'].shift())) &
        (g['Panel'] == 'Panel SP') &
        (g['Panel'].shift() == 'Panel GP')
    )

newdf = df.assign(gp_to_sp=df.groupby('ID Number').apply(gp_to_sp).droplevel(0))
```

Is there any solution for this?